# How can I make many to one relations in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, database-design

I'm writing an exam project. A summary of events is as follows; manager opens an exam and schools for the exam consists of a chairman and two members will establish a commission. Committee members will be selected from the staff table.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMDq3.png]

Comment: Can you provide the information in English?

Comment: Read here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189049.aspx

Comment: I designed the table again for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In relational database design, you need to use primary keys and foreign keys to relate tables to each other. A primary key is a unique identifier for a table and foreign keys are references to primary keys in other tables. Then you perform joins on your tables to get back the related data you want.

For your case, you need some sort of relation between the two tables that you listed and then you can create a many to one relationship. A many to one relationship consists of many records in one table relating to one record in another table.

For example:

```
tblCommittee
CommitteeId
Name
DateCreated
Person1Id
Person2Id   

tblPerson
PersonId
Name
```

Sample data:

```
Person
PersonId    Name
1           Billy
2           Joe
3           Bob
4           Jeff

Committee
CommitteeId    Name                DateCreated    Person1Id    Person2Id
1              Committee one       1/7/2014       1            2
2              Committee two       12/3/2013      4            3
```

Comment: I designed the table again for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks. I created sample data before you posted your updated tables. Unfortunately, I received downvotes while making changes to my answer. People are too quick to downvote.

Comment: how can i show this like;  
commite Name    Person1ID    Person2ID 
Commite one      Billy       Joe

Comment: I just used the code sample function in the editor and spaced each column appropriately. By no means does this need to be your table schema either. I was merely using it in the example for simplicity.